# Is this illegal syntax?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
  <!--
    alert('foo');
  //-->
</script>
```

It's used all over in my company's grails app, but I know `<` is an illegal javascript character...

Should the `<!--` be like `//<!--` instead?

Comment: Why would you do that? In Javascript you can either use // or /* */ for commenting

Comment: It's the old way to make sure JavaScript didn't show up as text if the browser didn't support JavaScript.

Comment: See http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hidingjs.htm (first link I could find which explains it)

Comment: yes, it should be escaped, but are you still supporting ie4? else you should use CDATA sections. and the actual illegal is the combination `</` AFAIK

Comment: @Michael — outdated though. It uses HTML 3.2 and doesn't mention the pointlessness.

Comment: @Einacio — IE4 doesn't need it. It is Netscape 1 and friends that do. Explicit CDATA sections shouldn't be used except in XHTML documents.

Comment: @Dave Newton — More accurately "recognise the script element". There are several browsers that don't support JS but don't render scripts as text (Lynx springs to mind).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not illegal. From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.2):

> The JavaScript engine allows the string "`<!--`" to occur at the start of a SCRIPT element, and ignores further characters until the end of the line.

It is, however, pointless. It is designed to stop browsers that do not recognise the script element rending the contents as text. The script element has been supported since **Netscape 2**! This makes the use of that syntax completely pointless today.

If, however,  you are using XHTML then it is actively harmful. Since script elements don't contain intrinsic CDATA, markup inside them is treated as markup and not CDATA, so it would actually comment the script out (if the document was processed as XHTML and not tag soup, which would require an application/xhtml+xml content-type).

> Should the `<!--` be like `//<!--` instead?

No, that would (partially) defeat the object.

Comment: But apparently stackoverflow doesn't ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's allowed, but it shouldn't be used. It was originally to prevent the JavaScript text showing up in Mosaic FWIR.

Answer (score 0):

It's the old way to make sure JavaScript didn't show up as text if the browser didn't support JavaScript.

See [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hidingjs.htm).

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be used.

It hasn't been required since Netscape 1.0

See http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html for what Douglas Crockford has to say about it.

Answer (score 0):

`<!--` is a special construct in Javascript, grandfathered in from the days when Javascript was new, and JS-unaware browsers were everywhere. In other words, Javascript understands and ignores the HTML comment opening tag. It's treated as whitespace, and serves only to hide the JS from ancient browsers which don't know Javascript, or don't even know what the `<script>` tag is.

The html comment  closing tag, on the other hand, is NOT a Javascript language construct, and must be commented out with a JS `//` comment.